# Audio Playback control in C++

Tags: audio, controls, synchronization, playback

I'm working on a project that requires me to sync an audio playback(preferably an mp3 file) with my program.
My program reads a motion file from a txt file and output's it onto the serial port at a particular rate. At the same time an audio file has to be played back on the speaker. This audio file has to be in sync with the data..that is to say after say transmittin 100 bytes of data, the audio mustve played back to a predefined time.

What would be the tools used to play and control audio like this?
a tutorial would be great!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In general, when working with audio, you want to synchronize other sources to audio. This is for several reasons, but most important is that audio runs on a clock running on its own hardware. You'll have to get timing information from that clock. There is a guide here written for using portaudio, but the principles apply to other situations:

http://www.portaudio.com/docs/portaudio_sync_acmc2003.pdf

Comment: but there must be a simpler way where by software coding i can just time the start of the music exactly..?

Comment: Depending on your hardware and environment, there may be, but there is usually a latency of at least 10 ms between when you start playing and when it comes out the speaker. What happens after that depends on how closely synched your clocks are, but if your audio file is short (< a few minutes) it may not matter. If that's sufficient for your application, then you may want to ask this question again with more detail about your environment.